# cocos2d-x Why i can't set sprite hierarchy when using SpriteBatchNode?

Tags: cocos2d-x

Hey i try to set sprite hierarchy to parent root , taking the example from SpriteTest.cpp
from SpriteSkewNegativeScaleChildren example.
but in my code i allso add the sprites to SpriteBatchNode .
like this :

```
auto cache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
    cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("leds/sprites.plist", "leds/sprites.png");   
    auto batch = SpriteBatchNode::create("leds/sprites.png");
    Sprite* Sprite_all_side_connector = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("all_side_connector.png");
    batch->addChild(Sprite_all_side_connector);
    Sprite* Sprite_one_side_connector = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("one_side_connector.png");
    batch->addChild(Sprite_one_side_connector);
    Sprite* Sprite_purple_stick = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("purple_stick.png");
    batch->addChild(Sprite_purple_stick);
    Sprite* Sprite_red_stick = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("red_stick.png");
    batch->addChild(Sprite_red_stick);
    Sprite* Sprite_yellow_ball = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("yellow_ball.png");
    batch->addChild(Sprite_yellow_ball);

     addChild(batch, 0, TAGS::SPRITEBATCHNODE);        
    Sprite_all_side_connector->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2));
    auto parent = Node::create();
    addChild(parent);
    parent->addChild(Sprite_all_side_connector);
```

but im getting exception , when i remove the SpriteBatchNode every thing working fine .
i want to use the SpriteBatchNode feature for OpenGL one draw call .

the exception is in :

```
parent->addChild(Sprite_all_side_connector);
```

[image: The compiler error]

Comment: all sprites in a batch node must use the same texture

Comment: they are using the same png image if this is what you mean 
but i like to use different sprites, like always do but in hierarchy
what im missing here?

Comment: what line does the exception occur and is there any error message in the log/console?

Comment: If your Sprite has parent then you wont add it until its parent in not NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create another instance of `Sprite_all_side_connector` and add that to the scene.  Sprites can only be added once. Change your code to:

`parent->addChild(Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("all_side_connector.png"));`

That should clean up the assertion.

Comment: so i will need to duplicate each sprite that i add to the BatchNode ?

Comment: Yes, if its been added to the scene once, you can't add the same one to the scene again even if it's in another node.

Comment: do i still get the effect from batchnode ? ( one openGL call) 
it there any thing wrong to duplicate the spirits ?

Comment: In your example you will not get the benefit of the batchnode call on the second addition since that sprite isn't part of a batch.  Only the one that was added to the batchnode will have the batchnode benefits.

Comment: i got confused , sorry .
let me get you right , if i add(duplicate) sprite that i already added to the batchnode i will not get the benefit of the batchnode.
so its best not to use the batchnode if i need to order my sprites in hierarchy? that is no way to use the sprites that allready created

Comment: You can set the Z value of sprites in the batchnode.  Then when you add the batchnode to the scene you can set the Z value of the batchnode in the scene.  So depending on what you are trying to do, you could create multiple instances of a sprite and layer them in the batchnode, or create multiple batchnodes and layer them on the scene.